Metro has encountered an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
Image Screenshot How to Resolve this issue of React Native.
the server returned response error code: 500
URL: http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform =android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com .figure1pro.development&modulesOnly=false& runModule=true
{"type":"Internal Error","errors":[],"message":"Metro has encountered an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile'): C:\ \Users\\Parvesh\\Music\\F1 Old Code\\mobile\ \node_modules\\metro\\src\\Bundler.js (48:30)\n\n\u001b[0m \u001b[90m 46 |\u001b[39m \u001b[90m// TODO: Remove this ugly hack! \u001b[39m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m \u001b[90m 47 \u001b[39m \u001b[36mawait\u001b[39m \u001b[36mthis\u001b[39m\u001b[33m. \u001b[39m_depGraphPromise\u001b[33m; \u001b[39m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m\u001b[31m \u001b[1m>\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\u001b[90m 48 \u001b[39m \u001b[36mreturn\u001b[39m \u001b[36mthis\u001b[39m\u001b[33m. \u001b[39m_transformer\u001b[33m. \u001b[39mtransformFile(filePath\u001b[33m, \u001b[39m transformOptions)\u001b[33m; \u001b[39m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m \u001b[90m | \u001b[39m \u001b[31m\u001b[1
m^\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m \u001b[90m 49 \u001b[39m } \u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m \u001b[90m 50 |
\u001b[39m }\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0m \u001b[90m 51 |\u001b[39m\u001b[0m"} 


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
